# two textviews in two layouts

Tags: android, layout

I want to have two relative layouts side-by-side vertically and put one text view in each layout. I want each layout to take up half of the screen (hence I used android:layout_weight="50". Here is the xml code for the main activity:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="helloworld3.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context="helloworld3.myapplication.MainActivity">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello World 1!" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:layout_below="@id/view1"
        tools:context="helloworld3.myapplication.MainActivity">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello World 2!" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

But the result displays only the first text view "Hello world 1!" and it does not display the second one, Hello world 2! Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Just add weight sum in parent layout and change its from Relative to Linear       
layout . Also In Child layout like two relative one add layout height to  
0dp below is updated code

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:weightSum="100">

<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/view1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="50"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Hello World 1!" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_below="@id/view1"
android:layout_weight="50"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Hello World 2!" />
</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want 2 TextViews one of top of another, taking 1/2 the screen each, just use a LinearLayout with vertical orientation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Text 1"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Text 2"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

If you do not want the TextViews to be 1/2 the height, you can wrap them in a FrameLayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Text 1" />

    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Text 2" />

    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use a horizontal linearlayout and adjust the weight to .5 for each textview and set the gravity of the textview to where you want it

Answer (score 0):

Your `RelativeLayout`'s are both set to `match_parent` for `layout_width` and `layout_height`

You need to set one of these to `0dp` for `layout_weight` to have any effect. The parent should probably be changed to a `LinearLayout` as well. By the way `layout_weight` value shouldn't matter as long as they are both equal: see below

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="helloworld3.myapplication.MainActivity">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/view1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="helloworld3.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World 1!" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:layout_below="@id/view1"
    tools:context="helloworld3.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World 2!" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to divide the screen half-half. you dont have to set `layout_weight` to 50. just set `layout_height`(as you want to vertically divide the screen) to **0dp**, then android will do what you want without considering the `RelativeLayout`'s height. so it could be like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="demo.drawable.propertyanimationdemo.HalfLayoutActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"></RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"></RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

use linear layout (Horizontal)

```
<LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:weightSum="2"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0sp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Demo 1"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0sp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Demo 2"/></LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

First off all i would suggest you to use Linear Layout for this purpose. the linear layout can easily divide the screen based on the weights given to it.

Below is a sample that will suit your problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
tools:context="helloworld3.myapplication.MainActivity">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView11"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="view 1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView12"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="view 2"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Apply this to your own layout and you will get what you want. do tell if it worked for you. Do accept the answer as correct answer.